# How does ECS Fargate distribute traffic across the available tasks when it receive messages from SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-sqs, aws-fargate

I have a multi-region ECS Fargate, running 2 tasks in 1 cluster per region. Totally I have 4 tasks, 2 in us-east-1 and 2 in us-west-1.

The purpose of the ECS consumer tasks is to process messages as and when messages are available in SQS.

SQS will be configured in just a single region. The SQS arn will be configured in the container running the tasks.

**With this setup, when there are messages from SQS, how does the traffic gets distributed across all available ECS tasks across multi-region?** Is it random ? Someone please clarify.

I am not configuring load balancers for the ECS task since I do not have external calls. The source is always the messages from SQS.

Comment: Do you anticipate there will be enough messages in the queue that one single instance polling the queue for 10 messages will not be able to empty the queue?

Comment: Also note that ECS and Fargate have no integration with SQS. It is the application you are writing that is polling SQS, and you just happen to be running that code on ECS/Fargate. ECS as a service does not do anything to distribute the load evenly here. It's all about how you design your system to poll SQS, and also if there will be enough messages in SQS to keep all tasks busy.

Comment: Thanks for you response Mark. 
Yes, I understand the ECS and Fargate have no integration with SQS. I have implemented the poller which will be deployed as ECS tasks to consume messages.

The SQS will have about 20 million messages per day which I do not think a single instance would be sufficient to process. Also, to enable fail-over, I want this to be a multi-task, multi-region event consumer. 

If ECS as a service does not do anything to distribute the load, how would the messages be distributed with all my tasks looking to consume messages ?

Comment: If you understand ECS doesn't do anything with the messages, then why do you ask how ECS will distribute the load? What do you realistically expect ECS to do here? With that many messages all your tasks will be polling, receiving messages in batches of 10 or so, and working constantly to process the messages. They should all be busy. If one fails the others will continue to work to "pick up the slack". There is nothing here doing any sort of explicit "load balancing".

Answer (score 0):

> With this setup, when there are messages from SQS, how does the traffic gets distributed across all available ECS tasks across multi-region? Is it random ? Someone please clarify

It's not random, but it is arbitrary. Here is what the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/standard-queues.html) say:

> Standard queues provide best-effort ordering which ensures that messages are generally delivered in the same order as they're sent.

The reason that it's arbitrary is because SQS queues [are distributed across multiple nodes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-basic-architecture.html) and you have no idea how many nodes there are. So if SQS decides that you need 20 nodes to handle the rate that messages are added to the queue, and you retrieve 10 messages at a time (the limit), clearly you're going to get messages from some subset of those nodes.

Going into the realm of complete speculation, [long polling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-short-and-long-polling.html) might improve your chances of getting messages in the order that they were sent, because it is documented to "quer[y] all of the servers for messages." Of course, that *could* only apply when you can't fill your response from a single server. I would expect it to grab all messages that it can from each server and return as soon as it hits the maximum number of messages, even if it hasn't actually queried all servers.

> SQS will be configured in just a single region. The SQS arn will be configured in the container running the tasks.

Beware that you need the queue URL, not its ARN, in order to retrieve messages.

Beware also that -- at least with the Python SDK -- you need to configure your SQS client's region to match the region where the queue exists (even though you pass the URL, which contains the region).